# Longest substring without repeating characters using vectors

Tags: string, c++11, vector

``
Given a string s, find the length of the longest
substring
without repeating characters.

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
        map<string,int> mp;
        vector<string > v;
        int ms=0;
        int l=s.length();
        if(l==1) return 1;
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            int cs=0;
            if(v[0]==v[s[i]])
            {
                cs=v.size();
                ms=max(cs,ms);
                v.clear();
                v.push_back({s[i]});
            }
            else
            {
                v.push_back({s[i]});
                cs=v.size();
                ms=max(cs,ms);
            }
        }
        return ms;
    }
```

i am getting below error
**"Line 518: Char 69: runtime error: applying non-zero offset 18446744073709551615 to null pointer (basic_string.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:527:69"**

Comment: You're trying to index into a vector `v` with a char `s[i]`.

Comment: On the very first iteration of the loop, this function accesses `v[0]` when `v` is an empty vector. Whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds.